# Unable to connect Zookeeper pod from Kafka pod in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run Kafka in GKE (*Google Kubernetes Engine*) I have created 2 pod for Zookeeper and 2 pod for Kafka but after deploying the Kafka pod is giving "CrashLoopBackOff" error and when I check the log it says "Connection refused".

###### Here is my `zookeeper.yaml`

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-deploy
  namespace: msg-ns
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: zookeeper-pod-1
      namespace: msg-ns
      labels:
        app: zookeeper-pod-1

    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zookeeper-img
        image: zookeeper:3.7
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
        env:
        - name: ZOO_MY_ID
          value: "1"
        - name: ZOO_SERVERS
          value: zookeeper-service-1
      restartPolicy: Always

  replicas: 2

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper-pod-1
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-service-1
  namespace: msg-ns
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-service-1
spec:
  ports:
  - name: client
    port: 2181
    protocol: TCP
  - name: follower
    port: 2888
    protocol: TCP
  - name: leader
    port: 3888
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: zookeeper-pod-1
```

###### Here is my `kafka.yaml`

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-broker0
  namespace: msg-ns
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: kafka-pod
      namespace: msg-ns
      labels:
        app: kafka-pod
        id: "0"

    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        image: wurstmeister/kafka
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
          value: "30718"
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
          value: 34.133.123.168
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zookeeper-service-1:2181
        - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
          value: "0"
        - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
          value: test:1:1

  replicas: 2

  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: kafka-pod
        id: "0"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
  namespace: msg-ns
  labels:
    name: kafka-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    targetPort: 9092
    name: kafka-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka-pod
    id: "0"
  type: LoadBalancer
```

###### List of all the k8s resources in msg-ns namespace

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/kafka-broker0-6cbb5df9cf-ss4fn      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   14         56m
pod/kafka-broker0-6cbb5df9cf-v5ds6      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   14         56m
pod/zookeeper-deploy-7c4b4b5596-kx4c4   1/1     Running            0          67m
pod/zookeeper-deploy-7c4b4b5596-pj5kg   1/1     Running            0          67m

NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
service/kafka-service         LoadBalancer   10.32.9.245   34.133.123.168   9092:31775/TCP               59m
service/zookeeper-service-1   ClusterIP      10.32.0.11    <none>           2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   67m

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/kafka-broker0      0/2     2            0           59m
deployment.apps/zookeeper-deploy   2/2     2            2           67m

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/kafka-broker0-6cbb5df9cf      2         2         0       56m
replicaset.apps/zookeeper-deploy-7c4b4b5596   2         2         2       67m
```

###### pod description

```
Name:         kafka-broker0-6cbb5df9cf-ss4fn
Namespace:    msg-ns
Priority:     0
Node:         gke-test-cost-optimized--default-pool-6c2f6d4e-q7gg/10.128.0.18
Start Time:   Wed, 04 Aug 2021 07:14:38 +0000
Labels:       app=kafka-pod
              id=0
              pod-template-hash=6cbb5df9cf
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.28.1.21
IPs:
  IP:           10.28.1.21
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/kafka-broker0-6cbb5df9cf
Containers:
  kafka:
    Container ID:   containerd://07ea801cd6cb22c574080b684ef249255f1398d4f31ef2f3074dc57069bebf9f
    Image:          wurstmeister/kafka
    Image ID:       docker.io/wurstmeister/kafka@sha256:4bad02cf8f07d0bf65d5cc73cce7aa75f9a90e32b585f867fce7c3fff229bd6d
    Port:           9092/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 04 Aug 2021 08:06:11 +0000
      Finished:     Wed, 04 Aug 2021 08:06:35 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  14
    Environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT:       30718
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:  34.133.123.168
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:     zookeeper-service-1:2181
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID:             0
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS:         test:1:1
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-f69fs (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-f69fs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-f69fs
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From                                   Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----                                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled  55m                   gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler  Successfully assigned msg-ns/kafka-broker0-6cbb5df9cf-ss4fn to gke-test-cost-optimized--default-pool-6c2f6d4e-q7gg
  Normal   Pulled     55m                   kubelet                                Successfully pulled image "wurstmeister/kafka" in 97.080502ms
  Normal   Pulled     54m                   kubelet                                Successfully pulled image "wurstmeister/kafka" in 101.651815ms
  Normal   Pulled     54m                   kubelet                                Successfully pulled image "wurstmeister/kafka" in 87.620654ms
  Normal   Started    53m (x4 over 55m)     kubelet                                Started container kafka
  Normal   Pulled     53m                   kubelet                                Successfully pulled image "wurstmeister/kafka" in 141.496724ms
  Normal   Created    52m (x5 over 55m)     kubelet                                Created container kafka
  Normal   Pulled     52m                   kubelet                                Successfully pulled image "wurstmeister/kafka" in 103.711978ms
  Normal   Pulling    19m (x12 over 55m)    kubelet                                Pulling image "wurstmeister/kafka"
  Warning  BackOff    5m4s (x205 over 54m)  kubelet                                Back-off restarting failed container
```

###### Here is the pod log

```
[2021-08-04 08:11:49,997] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:49,997] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:49,997] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:49,998] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:49,998] INFO Client environment:os.version=5.4.104+ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:49,998] INFO Client environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:49,998] INFO Client environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:49,998] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:49,998] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=973MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:50,010] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:50,011] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:50,016] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper-service-1:2181 sessionTimeout=18000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@4567f35d (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:11:50,032] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2021-08-04 08:11:50,100] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled= (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-08-04 08:11:50,106] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-08-04 08:11:50,130] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper-service-1/10.32.0.11:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-08-04 08:11:50,140] INFO Socket error occurred: zookeeper-service-1/10.32.0.11:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-08-04 08:11:51,289] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper-service-1/10.32.0.11:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-08-04 08:11:51,290] INFO Socket error occurred: zookeeper-service-1/10.32.0.11:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-08-04 08:11:52,392] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper-service-1/10.32.0.11:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-08-04 08:11:52,393] INFO Socket error occurred: zookeeper-service-1/10.32.0.11:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
...
...
[2021-08-04 08:12:08,109] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
waiting for kafka to be ready
[2021-08-04 08:12:08,921] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper-service-1/10.32.0.11:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-08-04 08:12:09,028] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-04 08:12:09,029] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-08-04 08:12:09,031] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-08-04 08:12:09,036] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:262)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:119)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1881)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:441)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:466)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:233)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2021-08-04 08:12:09,039] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-08-04 08:12:09,052] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-08-04 08:12:09,055] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-08-04 08:12:09,056] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2021-08-04 08:12:09,060] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using Helm or a k8s operator rather than manual Deployments/Services?

Comment: No, I haven't used any of that, I am newbie into Kafka. Do you have any refence or tutorial link?

Comment: That's not Kafka-related. It's k8s. Try starting here - https://strimzi.io/